# Javascript mousedown and mouseup event conflict

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, mousedown

I am creating a simple drawing website. What I would like to achieve is that my menubar should become unclickable, while my mouse is down (while drawing). This works all right, but upon `mouseup`, nothing happens. I have been Googling for  a pretty long time, but didn't find any solutions. Any ideas?

```
var mousedDownFired = false;
  $("body").mousedown(function(event){
      mousedDownFired =true;
       document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    
  });

  $("body").mouseup(function(event){
        
     if(mousedDownFired)
      {
         mousedDownFired = false;
         return;
      }
      document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'none';` you prevent mouseUp event from firing.

If you want to make your menubar unclickable just set it's style.pointerEvents to 'none', not whole document body.